# Cambio de poscisiones valores de report viewer

Tags: reportviewer, ssrs, reporting

Alguien sabe porque cuando muestro un report viewer para exportar a Excel hay dos celdas que intercambian sus valores de posición (imagen valor 1 intercambia con 2), cuando genero el Excel desde la web me sale de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando lo correcto debería ser de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien ha experimentado ese inconveniente?

Pd: ya me cerciore de que en las expresiones que uso si sean los Fields que corresponden en cada celda